# MVC Routing - multiple url's matching to a single controller/method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to setup a single controller to use 2 different URLs.

So what I want is to navigate to:

- mysite.com/MyArea/some-route/SomeAction
- mysite.com/OtherArea/some-route/SomeAction

and have them both go to the same place.

So I have a class set up like this:

```
[RouteArea("MyArea", AreaPrefix = "MyArea")]
[RoutePrefix("some-route")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("SomeAction")]
    [Route("~/OtherArea/some-route/SomeAction")]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

So this works - though looks a little messy.
I can type in either URL into the browser and it will pick up this action/page.

The 'OtherArea' doesn't really exist.  It's just sometimes I want to use the first url, sometimes the second.

1)  How do I route to this action and specify the url?

```
RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { area = "MyArea" });
```

I'm only specifying the controller/action - the URL it finds by itself.
Can I force it to use one or the other?

Ideally without hardcoding the path.

2) Is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do?
I'm not a fan of this line:

```
[Route("~/OtherArea/some-route/SomeAction")]
```

But I also don't want to create a copy of the controller and a new Area just for the sake of having a second url.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should place your logic in a method and use it in 2 defferent Actions

```
[Route("SomeAction")]    
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult MyAction1()
{
    MyMethod()
    return View("MyAction");
}


[Route("~/OtherArea/some-route/SomeAction")]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult MyAction2()
{
    MyMethod();
    return View("MyAction");
}

private MyMethod(){
 ....
}
```

But they can still share the same View

Comment: hmmm that's actually much simpler than I was expecting. Dunno how I didn't think of that >_<